# How can I get an address of a List?

Tags: java

I need to check if a returned list was created once or if it's a copy of an object. Is it possible to find out it's address?

```
// thread 1
List<Object> list = supplier.get();
System.out.print("list: " + list + "@" + getAddress(list));

// thread 2
List<Object> list = supplier.get();
System.out.print("list: " + list + "@" + getAddress(list));
```

How could `getAddress(list)` look like? The problem is that `hashCode()` which normally returns an address is overridden in `AbstractList`, so it would return a valid hash code instead of an address.

Comment: I was gonna ask "What address?", but then I figgured it out. Interesting question though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to find out it's address?

No. You can, however, check for reference equality - which is all you care about:

```
if (list1 == list2)
{
    // They're the same
}
```

If you really want to do this from logging, you can use [`System.identityHashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29) instead, but be aware that this is *not* meant to be deemed an address. It's still a hash code, and is not guaranteed to be unique. It may be *related* to some internal address, but that's far from guaranteed too.

Answer (score 8):

I guess you want

```
 System.identityHashCode(list);
```

the javadoc says

> Returns the same hash code for the given object as would be returned by the default method hashCode(), whether or not the given object's class overrides hashCode().

Comment: Wow! Thank you, that's what I needed. I will accept Jon's answer though, as it's more precise.

Answer (score 2):

The address of an object is not fixed in Java, it can move, so you can't get it.

Why don't you simply check `if(list1 == list2)`?

Comment: Now I've got what mean - JVM can move the object so it's physical address would change. +1